# How to "filter_immune_slice_fields" for date field in superset?

Tags: apache-superset

I want to immune slice date in superset and I also find out how to do that at https://superset.incubator.apache.org/faq.html but it's quite not clear. So, can anyone help me an intuitive example?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:
{

```
"filter_immune_slices": [3],
"filter_immune_slice_fields": {
"1": ["from", "to"],
"2": ["from", "to"]
 },
```

}

Which basically means for slice 1 and 2 you want filter fields `from` and `to` to be disregarded meaning if you have a filter that filters by either field, slices 1 and 2 wont be affected.